Can't find an element in the DOM even though it's there in tesim
I created a test which has the following steps:
Step 1: go a certain URL.
The page has a list.
Once the page is loaded, I validate that there are rows in the list.
Step 2: Wait for 5 seconds
Step 3: custom script to fetch a dropdown list and click on it.
const dropdown = document.querySelector('selector');

I always fail on step 3 and I don't know why.
I do see that I can get the drop-down when using the console, and I do see that it's in the DOM.
I have tried to increase the time but nothing works
Any idea?
